# How to rename (exposed in API) filter field name using django-filters?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-filter

As the question states - I'm trying to rename the filter field name exposed in my API.

I have the following models:

```
class Championship(Model):
    ...

class Group(Model):
    championship = ForeignKey(Championship, ...)

class Match(Model):
    group = ForeignKey(Group, ...)
```

I have exposed all of these models in REST API. I've defined `filter_fields` for the `Match` model:

```
class MatchViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    filter_fields = ['group__championship']
    ...
```

This way, I can filter for specific championship's matches (tested and working):

> curl /api/matches/?group__championship=1

Is is possible to use some kind of alias for the exposed filter so I can use the following:

> curl /api/matches/?championship=1

where `championship` in this case will be an alias for `group__championship`?

`pip freeze` returns:

```
django-filter==0.15.2
(...)
```

I've also tried implementing custom `FilterSet` with `ModelChoiceFilter` and custom lookup method:

```
class MatchFilterSet(FilterSet):
    championship = ModelChoiceFilter(method='filter_championship')

    def filter_championship(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(group__championship=value)

    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = ['championship']
```

With view:

```
class MatchViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    filter = MatchFilterSet
    (...)
```

But with no luck. The `filter_championship` method was even never called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After [Naresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3805509/naresh) response I have figured out the source of error.

It was the implementation of the model's view:

```
class MatchViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    filter = MatchFilterSet
    (...)
```

For `django-filter` it should be `filter_class` rather than `filter`, so the correct implementation is:

```
class MatchViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    filter_class = MatchFilterSet
    (...)
```

Also, I've changed the implementation of the model's filter to be more like Naresh suggested:

```
class MatchFilterSet(FilterSet):
    championship = NumberFilter(field_name='group__championship')

    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = ['championship']
```

The difference between above and the Naresh's one is the luck of `_id` part which is not necessary.

After these changes everything works fine.

Answer (score 14):

You need to provide model field as name in django_filters with field type. I am considering you are trying to filter by championship id.

```
class MatchFilterSet(FilterSet):
    championship = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='group__championship_id')

    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = ['championship']
```