# how to rename fieldname in django_filters

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a Django-based webpage and using the Primary key and displaying ***id*** field.
Here I am using django_filter and want to rename *id* field as *DSID*.

Can anyone know the way to do it?
any help in this issue would be appreciated

```
  from .models import *

import django_filters

class ShiftChangeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = ShiftChange
        fields = ['ldap_id', 'EmailID','id',]
```

[image]

Comment: answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992515/how-to-rename-exposed-in-api-filter-field-name-using-django-filters)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [**`label`**--(doc)](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#label) by

```
class ShiftChangeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    id = django_filters.NumberFilter(label="DSID")

    class Meta:
        model = ShiftChange
        fields = ['ldap_id', 'EmailID', 'id', ]
```